# I have a lot confusing boot options on startup

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

After I installed Ubuntu and did the recommended boot repair in it, when I restarted my laptop, I saw a lot of boot options as shown below. I think I should have just four items in the boot menu: Ubuntu, Advanced options for Ubuntu, Windows and System Setup.

[image]

Does anyone know how to delete the unnecessary items like bootmgfw.efi or fwupx64.efi from the boot menu?

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: you want the first option for a normal ubuntu bootup

Answer (score 0):

Some program (like Boot Repair or GRUB Customizer) installed the extra GRUB items by adding an additional file in the `/etc/grub.d` folder.

Here's what mine looks like:

```
$ ls -al /etc/grub.d
total 100
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 31 14:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 201 root root 12288 Jan 14 16:08 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  9791 Oct 14  2015 00_header
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  6250 Apr 22  2016 05_debian_theme
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 12261 Apr  6  2015 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 11082 Apr  6  2015 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1992 Mar 12  2014 20_memtest86+
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 11692 Apr 11  2014 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1418 Oct 14  2015 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   214 Sep 22  2014 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   216 Apr 11  2014 41_custom
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   483 Apr 11  2014 README
```

Using the `terminal`...

- `cd /etc/grub.d` # change to the appropriate directory
- `ls -al` # look for an additional filenames that I don't have in my list (like 50_custom)
- `sudo grep EFI *` # search for any "EFI" text that you recognize from your GRUB menu
- `sudo mv nn_filename ~/Documents` # then move that file out to your Documents folder (**don't move any files with names like I've shown above**)
- `sudo update-grub` # update the GRUB menu
- `reboot` # reboot the computer
- verify that GRUB looks normal

Comment: Please remember to vote/accept my answer if it was helpful.